# Extract a method used by two types

Tags: java, oop

So I've been working on some legacy code and this one caught me out. How can I reuse the `setNameAndSurname()` method passing in either the `Teacher` or `Student` object?

```java
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student();
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();

        // How can make both teacher and student to use the same setNameAndSurname() method?
        setNameAndSurname(teacher);
    }

    private static void setNameAndSurname(Teacher teacher) {
        teacher.setName("tom");
        teacher.setSurname("jenkins");
        teacher.setAge("50");
    }

    private static void setNameAndSurname(Student student) {
        student.setName("artemas");
        student.setSurname("prime");
        student.setAge("20");
    }
}

interface Person {
    String getName();
    String getSurname();
    String getAge();
}

class Student implements Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private List<String> modules;
    private String age;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name, String surname, List<String> modules, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.modules = modules;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public List<String> getModules() {
        return modules;
    }

    public void setModules(List<String> modules) {
        this.modules = modules;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

class Teacher implements Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String subject;
    private String age;


    public Teacher() {
    }

    public Teacher(String name, String surname, String subject, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

- Notice the instantiation of the objects in the `main()`. That means I cannot use the typical solution:

```java
if (teacher == null) {
    // use student
}
```

One approach I thought of using in this scenario was using the `instanceof`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student();
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
}

private static void setNameAndSurname(Person person) {
    if (person instanceof Teacher) {
        person = teacher;
    } else {
        person = student;
    }

    person.setName("artemas");
    person.setSurname("prime");
    person.setAge("20");
}
```

However, I'm not really happy with this approach as it is not very strict. For example, if I want to change `Teacher` or `Student` in the future, the `instanceof` approach might catch me off guard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already nonticed, `Student` and `Teacher` are structurally very similar, and already implement the same interface `Person`. This interface forces both classes to implement the methods `String getName()`, `String getSurname()` and `String getAge()`. In order to reuse the code within `Scratch#setNameAndSurname(...)`, however, the setter methods are required aswell. Without changing the interface `Person` or adding another interface, e.g. `ModifiablePerson`, I am afraid your solution is one of only a few solutions possible. I would only resort to this solution, if no other option is possible. The solution is problematic since it is not extensible. What if there will be a class `Child extends Person` in the future? You would have to add another `instanceof`-check. Normally, those checks tend to appear in more than one place. Over the time, someone will forget to update one of the checks. This is a violation of the [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

If, on the other hand, it is possible to either add a new interface or edit the existing interface `Person`, you can do the following:

```
interface Person {
    String getName();
    String getSurname();
    String getAge();
    void setName(final String name);
    void setSurname(final String surname);
    void setAge(final String age);
}
```

This then allows to simplify the `Scratch`-implementation:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student();
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();

         setNameAndSurname(teacher);
    }

    private static void setNameAndSurname(final Person person) {
        person.setName("artemas");
        person.setSurname("prime");
        person.setAge("20");
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/z6bJFO)

This is one application of [Liskov's substitution law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

---

A remark on the method name `setNameAndSurname()`: the method implies that the name and surname are set, but it actually has no parameters for name and surname to pass along. Thus, a more descriptive name would be `setNameAndSurnameToDefaultValues(...)`. Furthermore, the method also sets the age, which should be reflected by the method name aswell. This would result in something like `setNameAndSurnameAndAgeToDefaultValues(...)`, which is long and unhandy and why not do this through the constructor if default values are needed (after all, that is what constructor overloading and constructor forwarding can be used for)?

Comment: Mocking static methods hasn't been difficult for some time now, and bytecode manipulation exists throughout most Java stacks anyway. Presenting statements like that without any reasons does a disservice, IMO.

Comment: That was not the only point I gave. The other point was about isolation. My last information was that especially JaCoCo and PowerMock do not like each other (due to the fact that both manipulate the bytecode). And before I throw away my coverage, I rather let go of static methods. If this has changed, I gladly remove the paragraph though =)

Comment: Hmm... yeah I thnk I see your point. Agreed, will remove the paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the existence of a static `setNameAndSurname` method is really bad code smell.  What do you do when you are asked to add a new `VolunteerAide extends Person`?

More important, since `Teacher` and `Student` have common state (`name` and `surname` at least, probably more), it makes more sense for `Person` to be an abstract superclass instead of an interface.  Consider this instead:

```
public class PersonTest
{

    public static abstract class Person
    {
        private String name;
        private String surname;
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }
        public void setNameAndSurname(String name, String surname) {
            setName(name);
            setSurname(surname);
        }
    }

    public static class Student extends Person {
        // Student-only state and methods
    }

    public static class Teacher extends Person {
        // Teacher-only state and methods
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setNameAndSurname("John", "Smith");
        Teacher t = new Teacher();
        t.setNameAndSurname("Fred", "Bloggs");
    }
}
```

Now if you need to add a new `Person` subclass there's no extra work to do.

If `Person` absolutely *must* be an interface, consider using a default interface method:

```
public interface Person
{
    public  void setName(String name);
    public  void setSurname(String surname);
    default void setNameAndSurname(String name, String surname)
    {
        setName(name);
        setSurname(surname);
    }
}
```

This is sub-optimal because it still forces you to provide separate implementations for `setName()` and `setSurname()` in each implementing class when clearly the state is shared and you need only one implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `instanceof` like this - it is violating [Open Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) and will make this code harder to maintain (not only if you'll decide to change `Teacher` or `Student` but also when you will add another `Person` implementation)

What you can do is to either change `Person` interface or create new (then of course your classes needs to implement it) with proper methods

```
void setName(String name);
void setSurname(String surname);
void setAge(String age);
```

and create proper [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) like

```
private static <T extends Person> void setNameAndSurname(T person) {
    person.setName("tom");
    person.setSurname("jenkins");
    person.setAge("50");
}
```

Comment: You can actually neglect the generic parameter and just demand a `Person person` as argument =)